# Variable Undefined in Python Script

Tags: python-3.x, youtube-api, video-thumbnails

I wanted to download Thumbnails from a channel and I was using this Script that I found on GitHub.
https://github.com/rohitnairtech/YoutubeChannelAllVideoThumbnailDownloader

So in line : `pageCount +=1`     it says undefined variable

Also a HTTP Bad Request When Script Runs.I was just thinking I will tackle it one by one if this Undefined variable could be sorted out first.

I have replaced the required section with my Youtube API and ChannelID.
I am not a python programmer so I don't know how global variables work here or what could be a the solution to this.
I read somethings on Globals but couldn't find a proper explanation of what the problem here is.
[image]

```
def setURL (nextPage):
    sleep(4)
    global pageCount
    pageCount += 1 #Error Here
```

This code should download and store the thumbnails in a thumbnails folder that it automatically creates at root directory of script.

EDIT1:
pageCount is already defined in line 55 just before calling setURL shouldn't that work ?
Answer by Chetan Solves this Questions (That simple).
[image: Image 2 Code]

EDIT2:
ERROR Log after running the code:
These are self destruct links after use.

```
https://file.io/rE6BdY

 https://file.io/d9fyJb

 https://file.io/XsOXMw

 https://file.io/hrWZBS
```

Comment: Are you sure you defined `pageCount` outside the function which can be globalise?

Comment: @Saad Code is not mine. According to what you said ,I couldn't find any definition of pageCount outside this function. It has been declared Global just in this function.

I changed the code to :

global pageCount
def setURL (nextPage):
 sleep(4)
 global pageCount
 pageCount += 1 #Error Here

is that the correct way ? Because this still gives error.

Comment: Tell me a working channel id so i can check the code.

Comment: `pageCount` has been defined at line 55. Have you run that code as it is?

Comment: @Saad UCZPpGoR1Ak9TqxDJ5v-TC8g this is my Channel ID Uploaded a Video for testing. Thanks :)

Comment: @sentence Yes, I ran it as it is just added my API for Youtube and Channel ID where required.Yes, it is Defined at line 55 just before calling the function setURL which i am having problems with.

Comment: @Saad Recent Answer by Chetan Solves this but as mentioned by user::sentence pageCount is defined at line 55 before the call of function setURL()  the error occurs in.

Comment: There are more than one errors in the code. API_KEY, channel are not defined before the function. I use VS code and every variable is undefined

Comment: @Saad I am using VS Code too, I get only that error. After running the code though you get some errors and HTTP Bad Request. I will upload the error log.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
postCount=0 #you have to define it globally and intialize it first to use it 
def setURL (nextPage): 
    sleep(4) 
    global pageCount 
    pageCount += 1 #Error Here
```

Comment: This Solves it.